# Unable to connect MS Access DB in Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to connect the MS Access Database from the server and finding no luck.

I see the below image("Insert Operation Error") message while trying to save the information.

Can anyone please help? What went wrong in the below code?

[Insert Operation Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeU0g.png)

```
protected void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string constring = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DATA SOURCE=" + Server.MapPath("DB\\Contact.DB");
    string SqlString = "Insert Into BUREAUXDETUDES (mail1,mail2,tel1,tel2) Values (@mail1,@mail2,@tel1,@tel2)";
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constring);
    try
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(SqlString, con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mail1", txtemail1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mail2", txtemail2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tel1", txttel1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tel2", txttel2.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        lblmessage.Text = "Your Information Saved Successfully";
    }
    catch (Exception emsg)
    {
        lblmessage.Text = emsg.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you intending to connect to "Contact.DB" as in your posted code or "Contact.mdb"?

Answer (score 0):

The Error is telling you that the location of your .db file is incorrect.

You can change the path to the file in this line.

```
string constring = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DATA SOURCE=" + Server.MapPath("DB\\Contact.DB");
```

Comment: Thansk for your support  Estevez & Sarowar Hossen ,But I found no luck in result.I had tried bwloe both the options.Can any one pull me out from this issue please

string constring = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DATA SOURCE=" + Server.MapPath("DB\\Contact.DB");

string constring = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DATA SOURCE=" + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("\\webapplication2\\Practice.mdb");

Comment: BCode worked .string path = Server.MapPath("~/DB/Practice.mdb");
            string constring = @"PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DATA SOURCE=" + path + ";";

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Microsoft Excel engine first. 
You can download it from the link bellow
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255